# SQL Server - send data to cloud

Tags: sql-server

I am in the design phase of an application I want to create. Without giving too many details, I need some advice.

I want to send data from a local SQL Server 2008 R2 to a cloud application when data is changed on a table. My first idea is to create a table trigger that executes a custom console program. The console program will have to take in specific parameters and send it to the cloud application for processing.

Is this an efficient way to accomplish this? What are other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Trigger, OK; directly invoking an application, not so OK. Have it write to a service broker queue and have your application read from that (preferably a persistent one, like a service). This way SQL Server can focus on what it does best and your application can handle the cloud transmissions.

Comment: Agreed, triggers are gross.

Comment: Scheduled SSIS job? Log shipping / replication? A lot depends on how much data, how often it changes and how quickly it has to be copied. Or is the target something else than SQL Server?

Comment: Your comment should be an answer @JeroenMostert as it's (IMHO) the best solution--versus closing this as opinion based. Good comment regardless.

Comment: Agreed thanks for the advice